# On FW/1, do I need to return after doing a redirect?

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I have a function in a controller that looks something like this

```
void function edit(required struct rc) output="false"   {

   ...

   if (...) {

      ArrayAppend(rc.message, "<b>Error:</b> Something did not work right.");

      variables.fw.redirect(".home", "all");
      return;  // ?
      } 

   }
```

Do I need to `return` or does the redirect imply returning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the redirect method in the FW/1 source, you'll see it just does a regular cflocation.  That means, page execution will not proceed past that line of code so the return should be unnecessary.

https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/blob/develop/framework/one.cfc#L1031

**Code Snippet**

```
 ...
 location( targetURL, false, statusCode );
 ...
```